# executeNextBatch() doesn't always return a promise. nodejs promise/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, openai-api

I have a loop function that loops through a list of items and sets the image of the item if it exists on the database and if not, it generates an image for the item using openAI and saves it to the database while returning it back to the api. The issue I am having is that although the item image generates and saves to the database successful, I am having trouble an error of undefined when running the then function on the resolved promise.

I know I mixed usage of then and await but am a little confused on how to get this error resolved.

my function that matches images to item or generates new images for the item is:

```
function findImagesForObjectsOrGenerate(listOfObjects, images, isCategory, merchantId) {
  const MAX_REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE = 1;
  const requestsPerBatch = Math.min(MAX_REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE, listOfObjects.length);

  let promises = [];
  if (listOfObjects.length > 0) {
    listOfObjects.forEach((object) => {
      const matchedImage = images.find(image => {
        return object.id === image.cloverDataId;
      });

      if (matchedImage) {
        object.imageData = matchedImage.imageData;
      } else {
        promises.push(() => imageService.generateImageByNameAndSave(object.name, isCategory, object.id, merchantId));
      }
    })
  }

  // Define a function to execute a batch of promises
  function executeBatch(batch) {
    return Promise.all(batch.map(fn => fn()));
  }

  // Split promises into batches
  const batches = [];
  while (promises.length > 0) {
    batches.push(promises.splice(0, requestsPerBatch));
  }

  // Execute each batch with a delay between them
  let index = 0;
  function executeNextBatch() {
    if (index < batches.length) {
      return executeBatch(batches[index++])
        .then(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60000 / MAX_REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE)))
        .then(executeNextBatch);
    }
  }

  return executeNextBatch().then(() => {
    return listOfObjects;
  });
}
```

the function generateImageByNameAndSave that uses openai to generate and save the image to the database is:

```
async function generateImageByNameAndSave(imageName,isCategory,cloverDataId, merchantId) 
{
  try {
    // console.log("getAllCategories name: ", name);
    imageName = imageName.replace('/', ' ');
    const newImage = await openai.images.generate({
      prompt: imageName,
      response_format: 'b64_json',
      n: 1,
      size: "256x256",
    },{
      validateStatus: function (status) {
        return status < 500; // Resolve only if the status code is less than 500
      }
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log('imageName ' + JSON.stringify(imageName));
      console.log('e ' + JSON.stringify(e));
      if (e.data.error.message.includes('safety system')) {
        return 'something'
      }

      console.error(e)
    });
      const image = new Image();
      if (merchantId) {
        image.merchantId = merchantId;
      }
      image.isCategory = isCategory;
      image.cloverDataId = cloverDataId;
      image.merchantId = merchantId;
      image.cloverDataName = imageName;
      image.imageData = 'data:image/png;base64,' +newImage.data[0].b64_json;
    // console.log('image ' + JSON.stringify(image.imageData));
    console.log('cloverDataId ' + JSON.stringify(image.cloverDataId));

      const matchedItem = await image.save(image);
      return Promise.resolve(matchedItem);
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}
```

the errors I am getting are:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at Object.findImagesForObjectsOrGenerate (/cloverApi.service.js:178:28)
    at Object.getAllCategoriesWithImages (/cloverApi.service.js:93:25)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at Object.findImagesForObjectsOrGenerate (cloverApi.service.js:178:28)
    at Object.getAllCategoriesWithImages (cloverApi.service.js:93:25)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

the error is pointing to this part of the code in the findImagesForObjectsOrGenerate function:

```
return executeNextBatch().then(() => {
    return listOfObjects;
  });
```

this issue is executeNextBatch() doesn't always return a promise. How can I fix this without removing the batched promise limit.

Comment: if `index` is greater than `batches.length` you return nothing instead of a promise. Return `Promise.resolve()` instead

Comment: it didnt work, not the api isnt returning anything